# Character splitting in half when I rig

Tags: modeling

I am fairly new at Blender and I am trying to learn how to rig and create a character model. The problem is when I try to move my rig, my character model splits down the middle. How do I fix this? I am using a MacBook Pro Blender 2.91.2 [image]

Comment: If you used the mirror modifier then you need to make sure merge is on, if you aren't using that modifier then select all verts in edit mode and merge by distance.

Comment: I did try merging by distance but the problem still isn't resolved, also when I move my rig, a part of my character spikes out like in the middle of his chest.

Comment: Perhaps try rebaking the weights after merging by distance?

Comment: wait jk I think I got it! but still the spike in my character when I move his chest or stomach  is still there.

Comment: Probably something wrong with the weights, send me a google drive link to the blend file and I'll investigate

Comment: okay thank you!! What do I export it as? do I just upload my blender file to google drive? sorry I am new at this ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Is it this? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o-kXZSsyekIiJwio6I3gqIF8YNvSYOCa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yeah just the blend file, also I need you to accept my access request first

Comment: there I shared you the file and gave you access :)

Comment: Took longer than expected, here's your fixed Blend file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rhXvuLex1ggz4kRIpAjnKRQITi5ho8RJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: OMG thanks dude! I appreciate the help tremedously!! I was really struggling but If I have any issues is it okay if I can email you?

Comment: Did my email response go through? Just wondering since it seemed to piggyback off the google request-response email.